# error while build and publishing iot edge sample solution "/bin/sh/ -c useradd -ms /bin/bash moduleuser returned a non-zero code:1 "

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

running into this issue while building iotedge example solution(in ubuntu) from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux) document when target architecture is arm32v7. But the build passes without any errors when the target architecture was amd64 . I'm running this ubuntu inside a VM in windows10 pro(64 bit) machine.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this [Troubleshooting section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux#troubleshoot), Please make sure Docker Desktop should be running Linux containers. Could you please confirm if your machine is running Linux Containers?

Comment: An exec format error is typically caused when you try to run an application on a platform that it was not built for. Such as trying to run an AMD64 application on ARM32. You should make sure you have accurately followed all the required steps again when you switch to a new architecture.

Comment: Just checking back, Please let us know if you need further help in this matter.

Comment: my system architecture is amd64 running ubuntu. Can I build and deploy modules for ARM32 ?. I wanted to do in ARM32 because my AMD64 modules are failing with same exec error when deployed on RasberryPI 3 device(which is ARM architecture)

Answer (score 0):

"When developing IoT Edge modules, it's important to understand the difference between the development machine and the target IoT Edge device where the module will eventually be deployed. The container that you build to hold your module code must match the operating system (OS) of the target device."

"For example, the most common scenario is someone developing a module on a Windows computer intending to target a Linux device running IoT Edge. In that case, the container operating system would be Linux."

Please look at the key concepts in this document on '[Develop for Linux Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux#key-concepts)'

[image]